# Docker | CentOS | $releasever is "" when running docker build

Tags: centos, docker, centos7, mongodb, containers

I am attempting to build a docker image from a CentOS parent image ... and installing MongoDB. The error is happening when `docker build` is adding the MongoDB repo.

You can see that the error is happening because `$releasever` is blank for some reason.

**DockerFile**

```
FROM centos:latest
MAINTAINER "MyName" <myemail@gmail.com>
ENV container docker
RUN echo -e "\
[mongodb-org-4.0]\n\
name=MongoDB Repository\n\
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/4.0/x86_64/\n\
gpgcheck=1\n\
enabled=1\n\
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.0.asc\n" >> /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-4.0.repo
RUN yum repolist all
RUN yum install -y mongodb-org
```

**ERROR**

```
https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat//mongodb-org/4.0/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't escape the `$`, thus the variable `$releasever` was interpreted in your shell, instead of being inserted literally into the `echo` command output.

Try `\$releasever`.